# FirebaseApp with name APP_ID doesn't exist. Available app names: [DEFAULT]

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I have a react native app that has firebase modules such as

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14",
```

App is working fine with debugging mode, Apk is also fine, but when I publish it to google play internal testing, App is crashing after installing it with below error! There is no issue with app ids and json file. I have already double checked it.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
Process: com.app, PID: 26684
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name XXXXXXXXXXXXX doesn't exist. Available app names: [DEFAULT]
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source:83)
    at io.invertase.firebase.messaging.ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingModule.getToken(Unknown Source:0)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:148)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(Unknown Source:21)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(Unknown Source:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
2023-01-15 01:35:51.642  1629-2656  ActivityManager         
pid-1629
```